# HTTP error while accessing the nsetools library in python

Tags: python, http, stock, http-error

How to solve this HTTP error while accessing the `nsetools` library in python?

After installing `nsetools` via `pip install nsetools --upgrade`, I performed these steps:

```py
from nsetools import Nse
import pandas as pd , numpy as np
nse = Nse()
x = nse.get_quote('infy')
```

Line no. 4 returns this error:

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: The HTTP server returned a redirect error
> that would lead to an infinite loop. The last 30x error message was:
> Moved Permanently

I am working in Jupyter notebook and I have tried restarting the kernel, upgrading the library...

Comment: This seems like it might be a bug in the `nsetools` library or the backend it is making requests to.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I got the soln to this issue
Actually, the nse site is changed and that's why the package is showing these issues
The developer has pushed the working code in GitHub just download the package from GitHub and paste it into the respective directory
the working package is yet to release

pls refer to this link https://github.com/vsjha18/nsetools

Comment: Check spelling and grammar.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34830522)